# Does anyone know why using the stoi function inside a switch gives back constant error?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, switch-statement, compare

I'm trying to use the stoi function inside a switch but it keeps giving me back this error "[Error] call to non-constexpr function 'int std::stoi(const string&, std::size_t*, int)'"
I've tried multiple things, i even tried converting "PUE" into const int first and putting the variable in there but it still gives me back the same type of error saying that its not a constant expression. Maybe there is another way of writing this switch?

Basically I'm using a barcode scanner to obtain a string and i want to use the substr A to compare with some predefined data and display this on screen.

Thanks.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
string A, B1, B2, C;
string scan;
    cout << "Esperando a scan...";
        
    cin >> scan;
    cout << "Codigo:" << scan;
    
    A = scan.substr (0,3); 
    B1 = scan.substr (4,3); 
    B2 = scan.substr (5,7); 
    C = scan.substr (13,4); 
    
    //comparing

    switch(stoi(A))
    case stoi("PUE",nullptr,0):
        A << "PUERTA";
    case stoi("PAN"):
        A << "PANEL";
    case stoi("LAC"):
        A << "LACADO";
    
    cout << "\n Producto:" << A << "\n Acabado:" << B1 << "\n Color:" << B2 << "\n Nº Pedido:" << C;
}
```

Comment: As you can see I'm very new to this, I've tried reasearching on my own but couldn't come up with anything, and there are many things i still dont know. If anyone can help me i will appreaciate it a lot, thanks in advance

Comment: Letting alone the fact that you're using `switch` wrong (the cases need to be constant, you can't call a function in it), what do you expect `stoi("PAN")` and so on to return? `stoi` converts a string to an integer, and "PAN" can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: The expression in the case statement must be `constexpr` i.e. capable of being evaluated at compile time, so it can be even a call to a function. Sadly, `stoi` is not `constexpr` function (yet). Also, you probably misunderstood what [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) can do. `stoi("ONE")` does not return 1, it can only convert strings composed of digits to an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the suggestions provided by others:

checks performed by the switch statements are `static`. That means the expressions must be known at compile time. So you can't add any dynamic expressions while using switch case as you did using the stoi() function.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 switch(stoi(A))
    case stoi("PUE",nullptr,0):
        A << "PUERTA";
    case stoi("PAN"):
        A << "PANEL";
    case stoi("LAC"):
        A << "LACADO";
```

to:

```
 switch((A))
    case "PUE":
        A << "PUERTA";
    case "PAN":
        A << "PANEL";
    case "LAC":
        A << "LACADO";
```

I do not know why you would convert the string to int, you do not need it at all in the code you provided....